# Scaling a GAS Web App running as "user accessing the app"

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, quota

I'm considering implementing and publishing a Web App using Google Apps Scripts, which I'm quite familiar with for personal projects. I've never published a project to share with other people but I have an idea that would fit perfectly well for consumer users, probably for thousands of them. I've googled for the last 24hrs to see if there's any experience with simultaneous executions of a Web App when it runs as "user accessing the app" but I've failed to find any direct answer to my questions.

According to [Google Developers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), there is a <del>daily</del> limit of 30 simultaneous executions of the Web App, which coincides with the results of [this test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17512194/is-there-any-limit-on-number-of-concurrent-hits-on-google-app-script-web-app). However, neither the documentation explains on what conditions that limit would be reached nor the test was run with different users accessing the Web App authenticated.

Before trying to test it myself, which I find hard to do since right now I have no access to more than 30 different Google consumer accounts, **I'd like to ask if there is someone who has direct experience publishing Web Apps using GAS with permissions set as "user accessing the app" and has found errors beyond the 30 simultaneous users**.

Thank you.

Edited: 14/jul

Comment: First of all, the "30 simultaneous executions" is not a daily limit.  That is a limit for some unknown short period of time, which is not defined.  I don't know if it's "30 simultaneous executions" in one millisecond, 1/2 a second, or 1 second.  Whether that quota was hit, would depend upon each user's activity.  And that depends on how much usage you think that the Web App might have.  People often complain, that a quota is hit way before they think it should be.  It seems like you are trying to deploy a Web App to the general public, but have the web app count against the users quota.

Comment: Thanks. Of course, I'm not talking about daily limits. As I understand, the limitation would be 30 simultaneous users at any given time. It doesn't matter the time frame as long as, at any given time, there are 30 instances of the same web app running, accessing memory or cpu. But the question was other. The question is how those simultaneous executions are counted under "user accessing the app". Will they count globally? or to each specific user? I was asking as well whether anyone has real experience with this.

Comment: Sorry, and yes, I would deploy it to the general public, that's why this is important to know beforehand.

Comment: If the Web App is deployed as "user accessing the app" then it goes against that user's account.  It won't be added up globally.