# Google Data Studio Community Connector & Apps Scripts Limits (30 simultaneous executions)

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am in the process of building a custom Data Studio Community Connector for my web app using Google Apps Script. In my case, the data studio report is embedded as an iframe and the visibility is "public" for users of my application and I do not require any additional Google authorization (it is running as me).

Given that Apps Script has a maximum 30 simultaneous executions limit, does that mean that if I have 30 users simultaneously trying to view the report, I will hit the 30 simultaneous connections?

If that's the case, if I wanted someone else to be executing it, how would I go about doing that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Community Connector data source settings, I had to set it to run as Viewer (pictured below).

However, this prompts the user to authorize the community connector as well as to OAuth their Google account so the script can run as them. I submitted my OAuth consent screen for verification and it was approved within 48 hours.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

About the number of concurrent accesses to Web Apps, in my experience, when 30 concurrent users are accessed to the Web Apps, there was the case that an error occurs. You can see the experimental data at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50033976/7108653).

In [my recent experiment](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c2f3fccabbf4906a18fdc38463982f31), I have reported "Concurrent Writing to Google Spreadsheet using Form". In this case, in order to test the concurrent accesses to the Web Apps, I used the LockService in the script of Web Apps. By this, I could find that concurrent access to more than 30 users can be achieved. You can see the experimental data in the following figure.

[image]

But in this case, I think that this result will depend on the script of Web Apps. For example, when the script of Web Apps is complicated and the process cost is high, the number of concurrent accesses might become low. So please be careful about this. But, it was found that the LockService for Web Apps is important for concurrently accessing Web Apps.

Comment: Thank you, I gave you an upvote because I forgot about LockTask, but I don't think this specifically answers my question regarding Community Connectors and Apps Script.