# How to fetch form in Google Sheets and put in some data then download the whole thing as PDF file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, pdf, google-sheets

Suppose I have an existing predefined form in Google Sheets that contains something like tables with header columns and empty rows (waiting for data to fill in).

I am currently implementing a React web application that collects data from users. In the app, there is going to be a button, which is designed to do these steps that I would like to know if it is possible at all, if so how.

*User filled in some data in the web and then clicked the button.*

1. Fetch form from the Google Sheets.
2. Fill data in the form (in the predefined empty table rows)
3. Print the result in PDF (let the user download the file via browser)

Any additional third party libraries are acceptable.

Comment: In your situation, how many users will roughly  access your web application?

Comment: @Tanaike Estimated around 50+ users daily with 10+ concurrent users at any moment. It's a small website for a small community.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50033976), I thought that Web Apps created by Google Apps Script might be able to be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) So, how about using the Web Apps?

Comment: @Tanaike I will give it a try. Meanwhile, I will keep this question open in case anyone has alternative solutions. I'm all ears.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In another situation, even when Sheets API and Drive API are directly used in your web application, I think that your goal can be achieved. But, in that case, it is required to prepare the script for authorizing the scopes in your web application. I thought that this might be a bit complicated. So, from your actual situation of a number of concurrent users, I proposed using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike It is always helpful to give information and opinion (especially correct ones) to random people asking for help. I really appreciate it. I will definitely try your solution. I just also want to leave some space for other people that may have other solutions to propose.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you have questions, I would like to support you.