# Asynchronous function fails because of too many users in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a webapp in appscript, that renders an html page where users can submit data (sort of a form), on the backend I have a script that will get that data and write it to a Google sheet.
The script works fine, but as the number of submissions start to increase, my script begins to fail.
I'm wondering if anyone here could give me an idea on how I could solve this?

This is my code:

```
async function submitForm(time, caseID, inputScreeshot, projectID, workflow, language, policy) {
    
      var id ="someid"
      var sheet = await SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName('data');
      var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
      var timestamp = new Date(); 
     
      var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
      lock.waitLock(20000000);
 sheet.appendRow([timestamp,time,caseID, inputScreeshot, projectID, workflow, language, policy,email]);
      lock.releaseLock();
      }
```

I had to add the lock because the entries were getting overwritten, but I think this is what might be causing the problem.

I'm posting this from my phone so I apologize if the formatting is incorrect

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50033976/

Comment: There is two problems : overload and overwrite. The first is limited to 30requests/sec, so what is your scale, how many user do you expect to click in the same time? What is the error you get? The second is probably because of `appendRow` (which could be very long to write) and should be replaced by `range.setValues([ col0, col1, col2, ... ])`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering,  first question: how many users? This tool is being used by over 300 users.The second: what error? There are too many scripts running simultaneously for this Google user account., I tried a while back to use setValues, could try again. Another interesting thing that I noticed is that I've been working on a different approach with a new script and writing to a different file, but now even with only myself or a few people testing I still get the same error